# How to fit many graphs neatly into a paper?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, export, pdf-format

I got a graph list containing 110 highly irregular graphs with 12 vertices in the following link.

- [http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/graphs.html)

  ```
  << IGraphM`
  g  = IGImport[
  "http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/highlyirregular12.g6", 
   "Graph6"];   
  Grid[Partition[g, UpTo[5]], Frame -> All]
  ```

[image]

I would like to put these graphs in my paper (LaTeX). So I chose to print or export them to pdf, but both went wrong. The graphs went out of bound in the pdf.
[image]

I'd like to ask how I can get these graphs to fit neatly in my paper, like below.
[image]

Comment: If you use TableForm instead of Grid?

Comment: @demm I left my computer. Once I'm back my lab, I'll try. 110 graphs may be too many and may need to be placed in several PDFs. But some graphs don't go over the margins. I don't wish some graphs to be invisible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For 110 simulated graphs:

```
g = DegreeGraphDistribution[{2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2}];
SeedRandom[123];tabGraph=TableForm[
  Partition[Table[RandomGraph[g,PlotLabel->Style[i, 10],ImageSize -> 50],{i,1,110}],11],TableSpacing->{0,0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. It would be esthetically more pleasing to align the numbers?

Comment: Simply add after TableSpacing->{0,0} the option for the alignment i.e. TableAlignments->Top and all the numbers will be on the same level.

Comment: @demm Thank you very much. Because I want to insert these graphs in pdf format in one go into my thesis (LaTex). But your code output is OK inside the notebook, but when exporting, some graphs still **cross the border of a page**.

Comment: I tried reducing the number of graphs  per line a bit and it worked.

Answer (score 15):

You can use Labeled with graph:

```
g = Import["http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/highlyirregular12.g6"];

Grid[Partition[
  Table[Labeled[
    Graph[g[[i]], PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
     VertexSize -> .17 {1, 1}, ImageSize -> {50, 30}, 
     VertexStyle -> GrayLevel[.6]], 
    Style[i, FontFamily -> "Baskerville"], Bottom], {i, Length[g]}], 
  UpTo[10]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is great. But I can't give the best answer for both answers. So I chose in chronological order. This is very painful.